# Regarding usage of multiple jquery animate function for single div

Tags: jquery

from jquery animate doc i found a sample example where multiple animate function is used for single div.

doc url http://api.jquery.com/animate/

here is sample code

```
$( "#go1" ).click(function(){
$( "#block1" ).animate( { width: "90%" }, { queue: false, duration: 3000 })
 .animate({ fontSize: "24px" }, 1500 )
 .animate({ borderRightWidth: "15px" }, 1500 );
});
```

### here i have couple of question about animate function

1) why queue: false
why queue is false. what would be the result if queue was true

2) here animate use like animate().animate().animate() this way
so all the animate will run parallel or one after one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If `queue` were set to `true` then each animation would complete before the next one ran.

> queue: A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the
>   effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately. As of
>   jQuery 1.7, the queue option can also accept a string, in which case
>   the animation is added to the queue represented by that string.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/animate*

2) Well `queue = false` means that they will run together, and `queue = true` means they will run one after another.

Also you can animate several properties with one `.animate()` call like this:

```
$( "#go1" ).click(function(){
    $( "#block1" ).animate({
        width            : "90%",
        fontSize         : "24px",
        borderRightWidth : "15px"
    }, { queue: false, duration: 3000 });
});
```

But this requires the animations to all have the same duration. These properties will be animated all at once, not one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If the `queue` option is `false`, the animation will begin immediately even if another animation is currently running (assuming the queues are the same, which is the case in your example). Otherwise, the animation will be queued and will only run when there are no prior effects left in the queue.

That means your example animates the `width` property of the element without waiting for the current animation (if any) to finish, then waits for that animation (if there was one) to finish, then animates the `font-size` property, then waits for that animation to finish, then finally animates the `border-right-width` property.