# Using multiple animations (in a row) on a single element

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slide

I tried it this:

```
$('.element').animate({marginLeft: '-=1'}, 1).animate({marginTop: '+=1'}, 1).animate({marginLeft: '+=1'}, 500);
```

The idea of this is that I am IN REALITY animating slides with the top margin, but I wan't the user to SEE that it is animating from left to right. I can't just normally slide from left to right in my situation, otherwise it would be easy.

The code above didn't get me the result I wanted, it just lagged for a while and appeared really quickly.

Comment: might > [this link will help you check answer of this question ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976754/regarding-usage-of-multiple-jquery-animate-function-for-single-div) this is because of true false property

Answer (score 1):

I've found several different ways of achieving this type of procedural animation.
One effective way is to start an animation in the callback 'finished' function as Dio's has stated. 
But A more effective way is to use queues. The default queue is 'fx' but you can make custom queues. [I used this to help me with queues.](http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/06/22/how-to-use-custom-jquery-animation-queues/)

But if you don't like queue and want to be repetitive I made something similar using a setInterval function.

[See my beta example here.](http://www.benetosimonelli.com/slidertest.html) (still not published). See below for code example for you example:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
        sliderAnimation();                     
    });
    sliderAnimation(){
        var timer = setInterval(function(){
            slide();},500);
    }
slide(){
    var position $('.element').pos();
    var direcLeft = '-=';
    var direcRight = '+=';
    if(position.left => 499){
        var move = direcLeft + '500';
    }
    else {
        var move = direcRight + '500';  
    }
    $('.element').animate({marginLeft : move},500)
}
</script>
```

I haven't tested this code but it should move right to left and repeat as the distance, interval and animation interval have the same variable.